# Do nodejs dgram udp sockets have limitations?

Tags: node.js, udp, datagram

What I am attempting to do is ingest a lot of logs over UDP using nodejs. I ended up writing a decent bit of code to handle all of this. However, it appears I am losing a lot of the messages being sent over UDP when I am testing.

The simple code below will illustrate my problems:

```
var dgram = require("dgram")
, udp = dgram.createSocket('udp4')
, connections = 0

udp.on('message', function(msg){
  connections++
})

setInterval(function(){
  console.log(connections + ' msg per sec incoming') 
  connections = 0
},1000);

udp.bind(514)
```

All I do here is create socket and bind to 514. I use loggen (log generating tool on linux) to send 5k logs per second and my console looks like this:

```
2404 msg per sec incoming
2409 msg per sec incoming
2001 msg per sec incoming
2409 msg per sec incoming
2696 msg per sec incoming
2650 msg per sec incoming
```

However, then I increase the logs per second sent by loggen to 70k and my console looks like this:

```
30738 msg per sec incoming
32284 msg per sec incoming
35104 msg per sec incoming
34998 msg per sec incoming
34441 msg per sec incoming
33890 msg per sec incoming
```

I honestly have tried to figure out if this is a nodejs limitation or a UDP limitation or a NIC limitation, but really it doesn't seem like it is any of them. If Node can receive 30k+ messages per second at one point (despite it's lose of over 50%) why cant it receive 100% of the 5k sent previously? Regardless of the amount of messages sent it seems to be losing just over 50% of the messages.

Anyone have any suggestions as to what might be going on here? Obviously this is a very simple example but I see the same issues in my full code so the principles should probably be the same.

Comment: Try increasing the receive socket buffer size, increases latency but permits higher throughput.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Steve-o, I have increased the receive socket buffer size default and max and have similar results as posted above. Any other guesses?

Comment: I've run Wireshark and it seems that when I increase the message size I am sending to 1200 bytes the numbers are accurate for the number of packets being received by the NIC (incoming messages increase to around ~3500 as well but only ~3500 are received by the NIC). However, if I keep the message size at 200 bytes the packets received by the NIC are 5k per second and I am only seeing ~2600 per second in the program. I am not sure what to make of the behavior.